# How to reset the values of the table using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am working on a simple editable table with form inside it which i have to enable and disable using button or checkbox.

I want to reset the values of the table to its initial value when i click the clear button outside the table.

When I click that button ,I am able to set the state value  to its original state. In the table values for 'selectedrowkeys-> which is the keys selected using rowselection ' in the state can be refreshed but the datasource value remains the same in the fields .

Can anyone please tell me how I can reset the table values to its initial value?

```
    const data=[{},{},....]
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.initialstate = {
      dataSource:_.cloneDeep(data),
      selectedRowKeys: [],
      selectedRows:[]
    };
    this.state = {
      dataSource:[],
      selectedRowKeys: [],
      selectedRows:[]
    };
   }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: data
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
  oncheckChange = (index) => {
    const newdata=[...this.state.dataSource];
    for(var i=0;i<newdata.length;i++)
    {
      if(index==i)
      {
        newdata[i].enabled=(newdata[i].enabled==true)?false:true
        newdata[i].check=(newdata[i].check==true)?false:true
      }
     this.setState({
       dataSource:newdata
     });
    }
  }
  onSelectChange = selectedRowKeys => {
    const index=selectedRowKeys[selectedRowKeys.length-1]-1;
    const selectedRows=[...this.state.selectedRows];
    selectedRows.push(this.state.dataSource[index])
    this.setState({ 
      selectedRowKeys:selectedRowKeys,
      selectedRows:selectedRows
    })
  }
  onSelectChange = selectedRowKeys => {
      const index=selectedRowKeys[selectedRowKeys.length-1]-1;
      const selectedRows=[...this.state.selectedRows];
      selectedRows.push(this.state.dataSource[index])
      this.setState({ 
        selectedRowKeys:selectedRowKeys,
        selectedRows:selectedRows
      })
  }
  resetForm = ()=> {
    const newData=[...this.initialstate.dataSource]
    this.setState({
      dataSource:newData,
      selectedRowKeys:[],
      selectedRows:[]
    });

};
  handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('data to be passed : ', this.state.selectedRows);
            console.log('data to be passed : ', this.state);
            console.log('data',this.initialstate);
          }
        })
}
  handleChange=(event,i,title)=>{
   const newData=[...this.state.dataSource];
        if(title==="ratio")
          newData[i].ratio=event.target.value;
        else if(title==="remarks")
          newData[i].remarks=event.target.value;
        else if(title==="days")
         newData[i].days=event.target.value;
         else
          console.log();
    this.setState({
      dataSource:newData
    });
  }
  handleChangeDevelopmentDays=(event)=>{
      const newData=event.target.value; 
      this.setState({
        developmentdays:newData
      });
  }
  render(){
    const { dataSource,selectedRowKeys } = this.state;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys,
      onChange: this.onSelectChange,
    };
    const columns=[
      {
        title: 'Phases',
        dataIndex: 'phases',
        width:'25%',
        render:(phases, row, i)=>(
        <Form.Item className="uneditable" >
        {getFieldDecorator(`data[${i}].phases`, {
          initialValue: phases
        })(<Input/>)}
        </Form.Item>
      ) 
      },
      {
        title: 'Edit',
        dataIndex: 'check',
        width:'15%',
        render:(check,row,i)=>{
          return  (
              <span>
                <Checkbox onChange={()=>this.oncheckChange(i)}/>
              </span>
            )
        }
      },
      {
        title: 'Days',
        dataIndex: 'days',
        width:'15%',
        render:(days, row, i)=>(
          <Form.Item className="uneditable" className={dataSource[i].phases==='Development and Unit Testing'?"":"uneditable"} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e,i,"days")}>
          {getFieldDecorator(`data[${i}].days`, {
            initialValue: days
          })(<InputNumber/>)}
          </Form.Item>
          ) 
      },
      {
        title: 'Ratio',
        dataIndex: 'ratio',
        width:'15%',
        render:(ratio, row, i)=>(
          <Form.Item className={dataSource[i].enabled===false?"uneditable":""} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e,i,"ratio")}>
          {getFieldDecorator(`data[${i}].ratio`, {
            // rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input ratio!' }],
            initialValue: ratio
          })(<InputNumber/>)}
          </Form.Item>
          ) 
      },
      {
        title: 'Remarks',
        dataIndex: 'remarks',
        render:(remarks, row, i)=>(
          <Form.Item className={dataSource[i].enabled===false?"uneditable":""} onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e,i,"remarks")} >
          {getFieldDecorator(`data[${i}].'remarks`, {
            // rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input remarks!' }],
            initialValue: remarks
          })(<Input/>)}
          </Form.Item>
            ) 
      },
    ]
    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 16},
      wrapperCol: { span:6}
    };
    const buttonItemLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 1 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 6 }
    };


       return(
         <div className='App' >
            <h1>Name</h1>
             <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  >
                    <Table 
                    className='Table' size='small'
                    columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    bordered
                    rowSelection={rowSelection}
                    pagination={false}
                    /> 
                   <Form layout='inline'>
                      <Form.Item label='Total days' {...formItemLayout}>
                        <Input placeholder='Total' />
                      </Form.Item>
                      <Form.Item {...buttonItemLayout}>
                        <Button type="primary" htmlType='submit'>Submit</Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                      <Form.Item {...buttonItemLayout}>
                        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.resetForm.bind(this)}>Clear</Button>
                      </Form.Item>
                  </Form>
              </Form>
          </div>
       )

   }
}
const WrappedApp = Form.create()(App);
export default WrappedApp;
```

Comment: I am really sorry.It's my mistake i didn't mention it.The initial state of the datasource have some uneditable values like 'phases' which has some value.That has to be there when the table is getting refreshed.We can only edit ratio ,days and remarks which is either '0' or " " in its initial state.The problem is i can reset the state to its initial value but the table is not getting updated.

Comment: I am still trying to solve it but i don't understand where i am making mistake. I would really appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that in your state dataSource is an array.

If you want to reset the state, then you can simply do something like this

```
this.setState({
  dataSource:[],
  selectedRowKeys:[],
  selectedRows:[]
});
OR
const newDataSrc = this.state.initialState.dataSource.length = 0;
this.setState({
  dataSource:newDataSrc,
  selectedRowKeys:[],
  selectedRows:[]
});
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you Mohit.As i said i can reset the state but can't update the table value.The table value is still same as the value i edited.It is not updated to its initial state even after the state is reset.I hope i am clear now.

Comment: I think you got your issue resolved or still you're facing it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create methods that are modular and reusable. This way you just need to call the `this.resetState();` method everytime you want to reset the state. And if you ever want to add more fields in your datatable you will just need to change one method and this will minimize and avoid future errors.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.setInitState();
    this.state = this.getState();
   }

   setInitState = () => {
    this.initialstate = {
        dataSource:_.cloneDeep(data),
        selectedRowKeys: [],
        selectedRows:[]
      };
   }

   getState = () => {
       return {
        dataSource:[],
        selectedRowKeys: [],
        selectedRows:[]
      };
   }

   resetState = () => {
    this.setInitState();
    this.setState(this.getState());
   }
```

Comment: Thank you.I can update the state but the table is not getting updated except for the 'selectedrowkeys' as in rowselection which is automatically getting unchecked once i reset the state.But other column values is not getting updated.For example if i edit something in the empty remarks column,It is still there even after i reset to its initial values.I hope am clear now.